# Access localhost created by netbeans in Virtual Box

Tags: internet-explorer, localhost, virtualbox

Is there any possibility to access my application current running on netbeans in Virtual Box.

My detail situation is like this:

1. host Ubuntu- Netbeans to open localhost:8080
2. Has dependancies application also running on localhost- Database, solr...
3. Window virtual machine by Virtual box (to deal with IE)
4. Is there any way to access: localhost:8080 from VB and able to test application (connect db,solr...) just as in host OS

Answer (score 0):

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html#runConfiguration

Specifying the Default Run Configuration of the New Project

A run configuration is a stored setting for running a PHP project. You can define several configurations for one project and switch between them back and forth. For example, if an application has been developed locally and needs to be uploaded to a remote production server, you only need to choose another run configuration. Run configurations apply to both running and debugging. Run configurations accommodate the following common use cases:

```
Developing PHP web pages on a local machine with a local web server.
Executing PHP scripts using a local PHP engine. This approach is applied to PHP files that are not intended for outputting HTML. Therefore such scripts can be run without a browser.
Remote Development. The PHP source code and other application files are uploaded to a remote web server via FTP. This use case is common when the development is shared across multiple people.
A combination of the above use cases: an application is developed locally and deployed on a remote production server upon completion. During development, PHP scripts are executed if necessary.
```

When you create a new PHP project, you create the project's default run configuration. To set the default run configuration for your project, choose the relevant option from the Run As dropdown list on the Run Configuration panel. The following options are available:

```
Local Web Site. To use this run configuration, you need the Apache http server installed and running.
Remote Web Site (FTP/SFTP) (Separate tutorial). To use this configuration, you need a hosting account on a remote server and an FTP account on this server.
Script. This run configuration does not require that a web server be installed and running. You only need a PHP engine.
```

The process for creating additional run configurations, or editing the default run configuration, is described in Customizing the Project Setup: Run Configuration. It is almost identical to the process for creating the default run configuration, except that you use the Properties dialog of the existing project instead of the new project wizard.
Local Web Site

A local web site configuration involves a copy of your PHP source folders in the Web folder of the Apache web server installed on your machine. It is common practice for a project to have both a local and a remote web site configuration. Note that the procedure for setting up the local web site run configuration differs slightly depending on whether you are creating a project from existing sources or without existing sources.

To set up a local web site configuration:

```
From the Run As dropdown list, choose Local Web Site.
In the Project URL field, check the automatically generated URL address. Make sure that the Apache HTTP server listens to the default port 80. If not, specify the port number explicitly, in the format localhost:<port number>.
Project Run Configuration: Local Web Server
If you are creating the project from existing sources, you can choose which source file to use as the index file.
To store the project's source files in a different directory than the NetBeans IDE project, select "Copy files from Sources Folder to another location". If you are creating a project from existing sources, this is a required step, unless the existing sources were already in the web folder of your Apache server.
The field by default specifies the following path: <Document Root>\<New PHP Project>. Use the Browse button to specify a different path, if necessary.
The document root is the folder where the web server looks for files to open in the browser. The document root is specified in the web server configuration file.
The wizard detects the Apache installation type, either a component or within a package, and provides the path to the default location of the htdocs folder for the current installation type. Therefore, if you accepted the default settings during the installation of the Apache server or the AMP package, choose the path from the dropdown list.
Click Finish. The IDE creates your PHP project.
```

Remote Web Site

See the tutorial Deploying a PHP Application to a Remote Web Server.
Script

```
From the Run As dropdown list, choose Script.
Project Properties dialog showing Run Configuration properties, with Run As...Script selected
To specify the location of the PHP engine, click the Configure button next to the Use Default PHP Interpreter box. The PHP Options dialog opens on the General tab.
Project Run Configuration: Script. Specifying the path to the PHP engine and the output location
In the PHP 5 Interpreter field, specify the path to the php.exe file. Use the Browse or Search... button, if necessary.
To specify how the script execution results will be shown, select the relevant checkbox in the Open Result In area. The following options are available:

    Output Window. The results of executing a script will appear in the output window in the bottom of the NetBeans IDE window.
    Web Browser. The default browser window will open with the results of executing a script in the form of an HTML file.
    Editor. The results of executing a script will open as an HTML file in the IDE editor window.
Click OK. The Options dialog box closes and the system returns to the Run Configuration panel.
Add any arguments, such as debug=true, and any PHP command-line options.
```

Customizing the Project Setup

During the project creation, the basic project settings are defined: the project type, location of the project source files, and the default run configuration. To expand the project setup with new settings, customize the project. Position the cursor on the project node and choose Properties from the popup menu. The Project Properties panel opens with a list of settings categories.
Sources

On the Sources panel:

```
The Web Root field shows the root folder of your application site. By default, the field shows the Sources folder. To change the web root, click Browse and select another folder.
Select the Copy files from Sources Folder to another location, if necessary, and specify the path to the storage folder.
Change the encoding, if necessary
Managing project setup: Project Properties dialog box
To complete the project customization, click OK.
```

Run Configuration

On the Run Configuration panel, modify the default run configuration and/or define new run configurations, if necessary.

```
To modify the default settings, update the fields as during the project creation.
To define a new run configuration, click New next to the Configuration dropdown list. The Create New Configuration dialog box opens.
In the Configuration Name field, enter the name of the new run configuration and click OK. You return to the Run Configuration panel.
Define the run configuration settings in the same way as you defined the default run configuration during the project creation and click OK. The new configuration is added to the Configuration dropdown list.
To remove a configuration, select it from the Configuration dropdown list and click Delete.
Managing project setup: Run configuration   
To complete the project customization, click OK.
```